# How to remove object from array when Login User id is equal to Searched User Id-iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nspredicate

In my iOS application.,In my searching screen i can search all the users and I am displaying all the users in next view controller of collection view. but if login User Id is equal to Searched User Id then i do not want to add that name(login user id name) to my searchArray.(I have saved login user id in NSUserDefault, and saved searched user id in string from backend web services).
Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post code which you have used for adding data to search Array

Answer (score 0):

Well basing it on your problem without any code I assume you just wanted to check if your userID exists in the array?

```
NSString *req = @"is";
NSMutable *mutableArray = [@[@"this",@"is",@"an",@"array"]mutableCopy];
NSArray *tempArray = [mutableArray copy];
if([tempArray containsObject:req]){
  // req is contained in the array
  [mutableArray removeObject:req]; //remove the object
}
else{
  // req is not contained in the array
}
 // update the tempArray if needed
```

This answer is only a guess of what you wanted since you haven't put any sample codes on your question.

If its not the solution you are looking for let me know so I may update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get your searched UserId's array then you can check for current logged useId in you array with **array Contains yourObject or not**

for some better understanding i will give you an example you can replace it by your array and logged user ids

```
  NSMutableArray *tempUserIds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",nil];
  NSString *strLoggedUserId = @"3";

if ([tempUserIds containsObject:strLoggedUserId]) {
    //your searched array has logged user id so just remove it here
    [tempUserIds removeObject:strLoggedUserId];
    //reload your data display all the records

}else{
    //there is no logged user id is in searched array so display all the records
}
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

NSArray has a method called indexOfObject that will return index of your object in array, if such object is found, then remove that index from your array, like this

```
 NSUInteger index = [namesArray indexOfObject:@"User ID"];
    if (index != NSNotFound) {
        answer = [yesNoArray objectAtIndex:index];
        [yourArray removeObjectsAtIndexes:index];
    }
    [collectionView reloadData];
```